# Uniqueness and domain of dependence for wave equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

Suppose there is a spacetime. If I have two functions $u_1$, $u_2$ satisfying one wave equation, and there is a subset $A$ such that $u_1,u_2$ coincide in $A$, then do we have that $u_1,u_2$ coincide in the domain of dependence of $A$? If $A$ is a neighbourhood of a Cauchy surface, then this is true, and I wonder what if $A$ is arbitrary?

We can assume necessary smoothness.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this the definition of _domain of dependence_? If not, how do you define it?

Comment: @SFTP Given a set. A point is in the domain of dependence if and only if each causal inextendible curve passing the point intersects the set.